# type mismatch in QT 5.3.0 compile on OSX10.10

Tags: build, osx-yosemite, qt5.3

I am using qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0, and trying to build it on OSX10.10. 
After configure, when I run "make -j", I get the following error:

> qcocoamenuloader.mm:177:22: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type
>
> 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') with an rvalue of type 'nullptr_t'
>
> ```
> [item setTag:nil];
> ```
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/MacTypes.h:92:19: note:
>
> ```
> expanded from macro 'nil'
>
> #define nil nullptr
> ```
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSMenuItem.h:115:21: note:
>
> passing argument to parameter 'tag' here
>
> @property NSInteger tag;
>
> 1 error generated.
>
> make[5]: *** [.obj/qcocoamenuloader.o] Error 1
>
> make[4]: *** [sub-cocoa-make_first] Error 2
>
> make[3]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
>
> make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
>
> make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2

To me it looks like the Mac SDK is defining nil to be nullptr and this caused a problem. Is there a way to work around this?

My configure call looks like this:

> ./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -qt-harfbuzz -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -no-pch -nomake examples -nomake tools -verbose -arch x86_64